# C#: Send input from inactive window

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, window

I'm trying to send input from a WPF `Window` which doesn't have focus. The idea is to create a virtual numpad, whereby pressing `Alt+M` for example sends `Alt+Numpad0`. I've got Michael Kennedy's [global hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx?fid=35025&fr=51&select=932717) working, but I can't find a way to:

1) Send keys from an inactive window

2) Swallow these keys so they're not processed by the application which has focus.

The second may become a non-issue once I get the first fixed.

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` didn't work for this because I need to simulate the `Alt+xxx` combinations to generate the right characters. I also tried `System.Windows.Input.InputManager.Process()` from an [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3d014196-c4bc-41b7-a3f8-bf5065e5fa03), but if the Window sending the input doesn't have focus, the InputSource I was using (second parameter - `Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource`) is null.

Any ideas?

Why a virtual numpad? Without a numpad on my laptop (Studio 1555) I can't enter symbols without opening charmap - thanks Dell!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) for simulating keystrokes. Or use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to grab any keystroke and resend it as some other keystroke.